# Prove or disprove: no universal chain rule for indefinite integrals

Tags: calculus

In differentiation, we have a good closed form for differentiation of chain functions(namely the chain rule): $$\frac{d}{dx}a(b(x))=a’(b(x))b’(x)$$ which is a finite combination of $\{a(x), b(x), a’(x), b’(x)\}$.

An expression is a ‘finite combination’ of a set of functions $\{f_n(x)\}$ if the expression can be written in terms of $\{f_n(x)\}$ by finitely many linear combinations, products, quotients, compositions, powers, and adding of constants.

As far as I know, there is no chain rule for indefinite integrals. But, can we prove it?

Precisely,

> Let $f(x), g(x):\mathbb 
> R\mapsto\mathbb R$ be continuous, differentiable functions.
>
> Let $F(x), G(x)$ be their antiderivatives respectively.
>
> Prove or disprove the existence of an expression that equals $$\int f(g(x))dx$$ for any $f(x),g(x)$, where the expression is a finite combination of $\{f(x),g(x),F(x),G(x)\}$.

My primary thoughts:

Let $$\int f(g(x))dx=L(f(x),g(x),F(x),G(x))$$

Then one should prove $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}L\ne 0$$

However, I cannot rigorously justify this approach. Moreover, this might be even wrong.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

An answer providing the solution to a similar problem for the universal product rule for indefinite integrals will also be welcomed.

Comment: The Risch algorithm will do the job already. Consider $f=\exp,g=x^2$.

Comment: @Ian Can you elaborate?

Comment: The result you want to disprove in fact fails quite spectacularly, because for $f(x)=e^x,g(x)=x^2$, the antiderivative isn't even an elementary function, much less a finite combination of $e^x,x^3$ and constants. The Risch algorithm is the standard tool to prove that rigorously.

Comment: @Ian I was expecting some answers of higher genrality, but indeed one counter-example already completes the disproof.